# Travelling with two passports (dual citizen) from the Philippines to China then to Japan

Tags: japan, china

I am planning a trip from the Philippines to China and then continuing to Japan, before heading back to the Philippines. I am a dual citizen of the Philippines and Sweden.

I have a Chinese visa on my Philippines passport, which I will use to enter and exit China, but can I then use my Swedish passport to enter Japan (from China)? Will I have problems at either the Chinese or Japanese Immigration? The reason I want to do this is to avoid having to apply for a Japanese tourist visa for my Philippines passport and instead use my Swedish passport, which is visa free for travel to Japan.

I know that the Chinese border control will look for an entry stamp on my Philippines passport when exiting China, so I can show this passport. But if they then ask me to show my Japanese visa for my onward flight to Japan, would it then be acceptable if I just show my Swedish passport?

Another option would be to book an ongoing flight to Japan that transfers through Hong Kong (visa-free for both of my passports). Which would be a better option?

Thank you for any advice and tips!

Answer (score 8):

As a foreigner, when you leave China, China Immigration won't care where you are going, and whether you have the visa for it: that has been checked already by the airline staff.

This is where you'll have to show both passports: at the airline counter, during check-in. They'll see you have a Chinese visa and entry stamp on your PHP passport, and that your Swedish passport gives you visa-free access in Japan. When you land in Japan, use your Swedish passport.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This is exactly what I need to know ☺️ I got worried as I read in another thread that Chinese border control checks if you have visa for ongoing destination, but perhaps they only applies if you’re a Chinese national.

Comment: @sr.py CN Immigration has different priorities on entry and exit, and with CN nationals vs foreigners. I've entered (and exited!) Mainland China a few hundred times, and was never asked about visas and the likes at Immigration, only by airlines. Exit checks are noticeably faster than entry, as you'll see.

Comment: Oh that’s great news! Thanks a lot for your help 